# Not able to sort the columns

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, datatables, handlebars.js

This is approximately how I want to display the tables
[image: http://os6.org/upload/?di=AOYK]

http://os6.org/upload/?di=AOYK

```
<table class="dataTable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="sortable">Sr. No.
        <span class="sortIcon"></span></th>
    <th class="sortable">First Name
        <span class="sortIcon"></span></th>
    <th class="sortable">Last Name
        <span class="sortIcon"></span></th>
    <th class="sortable">Email
        <span class="sortIcon"></span></th>
    <th class="sortable">Address
        <span class="sortIcon"></span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
    {{#each sideTables}}
        <tr class="category">
            <td colspan="5">
                <div>
                    <span>{{tableName}}</span>
                    <span>{{tableRelation}}</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{#each collectionAttribute}}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
         {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</table>    
<br>
```

In firebug, 
jquery is giving me following error:
`TypeError: m is undefined.`

If I remove the following code sorting works, but I need the following code to meet my software requirements.

```
<tr class="category">
    <td colspan="5">
        <div>
            <span>{{tableName}}</span>
            <span>{{tableRelation}}</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please visit: http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html

I am able to arrange in group, but sorting is not working...